# How to set sender Address when sending message to co-ordinator in Jgroups

Tags: java, jgroups

We can send a message to the co-ordinator using the Message() object. Here we have to set the sender address and the receiver address. If I want to send a message to the co-ordinator, then I can take the get(0) member from the view and use that as the destination addresss. But how do I set the sender address, should I use the IP address of my current machine, the MAC address or some other address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the sender's address; the stack will fill it in for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add you can do a point to point as well

```
Address  newAddress = getAddress();
org.jgroups.Message performMessage = new org.jgroups.Message();
performMessage.setDest(newAddress);
getChannel.send(performMessage);
```